# Access control issue in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, access-control

I have an admin panel and now I need to give some partners a URL to see their specified data. I have a table for storing these partners login info and authentication is done through it. But the problem now is that after authentication, partners can access each of the other admin pages. I can include a check in every admin page controller to check whether the session is set for partner and if so I can logout them. But I have a number of controllers. So is there any other methods for doing this same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pǝlɐɥʞ's solution will defenitely work but you would need to edit all of your controllers. I'd like to point you to another approach. CodeIgniter provides a Hook functionality (not the best, but still better than nothing). Hooks provide the functionality to execute code before certain actions in the CodeIgniter core happen.

For your purpose I'd suggest to use the 'post_controller_constructor' hook which will be executed after a controller gets instantiated, but before any method calls are happening.

For a reference look here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/hooks.html

Your hook could look like this

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'] = array(
    'class'    => 'Auth',
    'function' => 'has_permission',
    'filename' => 'Auth.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks',
);
```

**Update**

By grabbing an instance of CodeIgniter ($ci =& get_instance()) you will be able to use all the functionality of the framework inside your class you pass to your hook (just like writing your own CI Library). So you can check there for sessions and handle user permissions.

**Update 2**

ruuter called my attention to use **post_controller_constructor** instead of **pre_controller** which allows the usage of **get_instance()** (which would not be available using **pre_controller**). The downside of using **post_controller_constructor** is, that the controllers constructor will always be called before checking for permissions which might cause trouble in certain situations.

-Thanks to ruuter for this information

Happy Coding :)

Comment: It should be noted that `$ci =& get_instance()` is NOT available in `pre_controller` hook. You can use `post_controller_constructor` hook to get CI instance. This hook is called after controller is instantiated, but prior to any method calls happening.

Comment: I did not use CI for more than half a year now. When I wrote this answer I have not tested this. Thank you! I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

Dunno which version of codeigniter you are using, so can't tell you the exact location.. but you can create a controller called MY_Controller, which extends CI_Controller.

Then all your controllers can extend MY_controller.

MY_Controller can have the functionality you require that is common to all the controllers you speak about.

See the bottom of this page http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html

Comment: That's fine. But for it also, I need to edit all the controllers